# Can you set async defer when using {% includeJsFile %}?

Tags: includejs

Is there a way to set `async defer` on a `<script>` tag with the built in:

```
{% includeJsFile %}
```

It's for Google Maps e.g.:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

I'd still like to be able to output this at the bottom of the layout from within another template. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as of [Craft 2.6.2791](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2791).

If that's a requirement for you, you can not use that tag and put a block in your footer and manually create the script tag with `async defer` set.

Comment: thanks for the feedback Brad - i'll look in to an alternative way of implementing it.

Comment: @alexr how did you implement this in the end? I am currently at the same conundrum.

Comment: @TerryUpton i think in the end i ended up manually putting it in the footer of my site in an if statement. In this particular site I was setting a title var in each template in twig anyway, and only had a map on one page, so i ended up doing something like {% if title == 'mappage' %}<script src="path/to/script" async defer></script>{% endif %}

Answer (score 8):

As of Craft 3 (Tested using [RC5](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/releases/tag/3.0.0-RC5)) you can do it like this:

```
{% do view.registerJsFile("path/to/script.js", {"async":"async", "defer":"defer"}) %}
```

Source: [Documentation for Yii's view.registerJsFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail)

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that `<script>`s are imploded with [\n](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/2.6.2986/src/services/TemplatesService.php#L760) char. You can add async defer this way:

```
{%- set scripts = getFootHtml() | split("\n")  -%}
{%- for script in scripts -%}
    {%- if script matches "%\/assets\/js\/main\.js%" or ' src=' not in script -%}
        {{- script | raw -}}
    {%- else -%}
        {{- script | replace('script type', 'script async defer type') | raw -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```